# Convert string to FontAwesome icon and assign to icon field

Tags: c#, wpf, font-awesome

I have a xml to save FontAwesome icon as string like

```
 <Icon Name="faMainMenuFile">
      <Content>FolderOutline</Content>
      <Size>50</Size>
    </Icon>
```

So I parse the xml file, I will get FolderOutline string

but assign the icon field is

```
faMainMenuFile.Icon = FontAwesome.WPF.FontAwesomeIcon.FolderOutline
```

I try to create a function to convert string to FontAwesome.WPF.FontAwesomeIcon

```
public FontAwesome.WPF.FontAwesomeIcon GetUIFontAwesome(string strIcon)
    {
        if(strIcon == "Calculator") return FontAwesome.WPF.FontAwesomeIcon.Calculator;
        if (strIcon == "FolderOutline") return FontAwesome.WPF.FontAwesomeIcon.FolderOutline;

        return FontAwesome.WPF.FontAwesomeIcon.None;
    }
```

But I will create giant list to handle this feature,

How can I fix it ?

Comment: If the name matches the field / property, you can use reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to  convert string to enum :

```
public FontAwesome.WPF.FontAwesomeIcon GetUIFontAwesome(string strIcon)
{
    FontAwesome.WPF.FontAwesomeIcon item;
    if (Enum.TryParse(strIcon, out item))
        return item;
    else 
        return FontAwesome.WPF.FontAwesomeIcon.None; 
}
```